# Change div bgcolor onkeypress

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to change the background color of all my divs using a onkeypress event. R = Red , B=White, V=Green. When press R it works but when i press V or B it gives me the alert. 
I tried without return, with a switch(actualy im supposed to do this with a switch). Teacher cancelled class today so I wasnt able to check it out with him .And I Wont see him til next week. I tried things and other things for 2-3 hours and im totaly stuck Please help.. Thanks in advance

```
    window.onkeypress = function colorchange(x)
    { 
        if (x.keyCode == 114)
           { var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
            {
            divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }return;
           }
        if (x.keycode == 118)
           {
            var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
            {
            divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }return;
           }
        if (x.keycode == 98)
         {

           var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
            {
            divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }return;
         }
         else 
         {
             alert("this key doesnt do anything")

         }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `x.keycode` instead of `x.keyCode` in the second and third `if` statements. You should also chain the conditions using `else if`.

```
window.onkeypress = function colorchange(x)
{ 
    if (x.keyCode === 114) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    return;
  }
  else if (x.keyCode === 118)
  {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    return;
  }
  else if (x.keyCode === 98)
  {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    return;
  }
  else 
  {
    alert("this key doesnt do anything")
  }
}
```

See [working jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x7xLj0gn/).

Comment: ahah ouch this one hurts! Everything is fine now.. note It doesnt work on firefox but chrome is all good!

Comment: @FrankCharron you should use `x.which` which works for most cases.
`var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);`

See here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Answer (score 1):

The variables are case-sensitive. You have `keycode` and it should be `keyCode`. Looks like you should also be using `else if()`.

```js
window.onkeypress = function colorchange(x) {
  if (x.keyCode == 114) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    return;
  } else if (x.keyCode == 118) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    return;
  } else if (x.keyCode == 98) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    return;
  } else {
    alert("this key doesnt do anything")
  }
}
```

```css
body {
background: #eee;
}

div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```